# Converting a str to an int

Tags: python

My Problem is that the type `'ip'` is str, but i need integer.

So i did the convert `int(ip)`. Then i got error

> invalid literal for int() with base 10:

So i did a little bit of research and found that i had to put int `int(float(ip))`.

Now i get "could not convert string to float".

```
import socket
def retrieveBanner(ip, port):
    s = socket.socket()
    s.connect((int(float(ip)),port))
    banner = s.recv(1024).decode()
    print("Bitte geben Sie eine IP und ein Port ein")

ip = input("IP? ")
port = input("Port? ")
retrieveBanner(ip, port)
if ("NASFTPD" in banner):
    print("Vulnerable")
```

Comment: Based on the code, and the name of the var, you are dealing with an IP right? So is it safe to assume that your data is something like: `127.0.0.1`? Can you please show what data you are dealing with?

Comment: Please, specified some input you are use.

Comment: IP must be string and port must be integer

Comment: Try with `s.connect(("IP_as_string",int(port)))`

Comment: `s.connect(ip, int(port))` is it fine?

Comment: @idjaw yes ur right. in IP i enter : 192.168.10.23

Comment: IPs are neither integers nor floats.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.connect), `connect` expects a tuple `(string, int)`, with the string being the ip address and the int being the port. You can modify your code this way to fix it :

```
s.connect((ip, int(port)))
```

Hope it'll be helpful.

Comment: Thanks that worked for me... man the solution was so simple -.- thanks anyway :)

Comment: `raw_input` is not there in python 3.x. So based on input inside code, it has to converts `int` if needed(since `input` will always returns `str` in `3.x`).

Answer (score 0):

To convert a dotted notation IP address in a string to an integer you need:

```
i_ip = socket.inet_aton(ip)
```

"aton" is short for "ASCII to number".  This is for IPv4 addresses.